# looking for hosted vcs for visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, version-control

I travel a bit and I'm looking for a hosted vcs with good support for Visual Studio.  My projects aren't open source so I need security as well.  Any recommendations or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming VCS means Version Control System in this context, try [www.codesion.com](http://www.codesion.com)? They have a free plan or you can pay... if security is an issue I'd probably prefer a professional place.

Comment: thanks--i appreciate the pointer!

Comment: it's worth pointing out there are many alternatives but they are fairly good and I think you get 200Mb on the free plan to try with

Comment: yep, I'm finding them now.  I was looking in the wrong places before; thanks for the help.